# JQuery - Remove Resize Functionality

Tags: jquery, resize

I have made a DIV resizable in jQuery, like this:

```
$("#myDiv").resizable();
```

Simple,

Now is there a way make it 'un' resizable, and to remove this functionality all together?

Regards.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You want the destroy function:

`$('#myDiv').resizable('destroy');`